# jquery ui datepicker not working with tabs

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, tabs, datepicker

When a user switches tabs in the jquery ui code they can click on a button to add data to a jqgrid. The only thing that is not working is datepicker; it will launch one time and after that when switching to a new tab it will not launch again.

source document code;

```
<link href="/Includes/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Includes/jqgrid/css/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Includes/jqgrid/src/css/ui.jqgrid.css">
<script src="/Includes/jqgrid/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Includes/jqgrid/css/jquery-ui-1.11.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Includes/jqgrid/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
<script src="/Includes/jqgrid/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Includes/validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Includes/validation/dist/additional-methods.min.js"></script>

$("#tabs").tabs(
{
    //each tab activation
    activate:function(event, ui)
    { loadGrid(); },
    beforeActivate:function(event, ui)
    {
        var curTab = $('#tabs .ui-tabs-active');
        var curTabName = curTab.text();
        var pos = curTabName.search('-');
        var curID = curTabName.slice(0,pos); 

        var passFrmDiv = "div[id^=adddaydata" + curID + "]";

        $(passFrmDiv).html("");
    }
}); 

function loadGrid()
{
    var curTab = $('#tabs .ui-tabs-active');
    var curTabName = curTab.text();
    var pos = curTabName.search('-');
    var newID = curTabName.slice(0,pos); 

    //reset adddaydata
        $("div[id^=adddaydata" + newID + "]").text('');

    //load form
        var getFrmURL = '90daywellform.php?id=' + newID + '&d=' + $.now();
        var passFrmDiv = "div[id=wellform" + newID +"]";

        $.get(getFrmURL, function(data)
        { $(passFrmDiv).html(data); }); 
        //$(passFrmDiv).load('90daywellform.php?id=' + newID + ' #loadform');

    //load grid
        var getGrdURL = '90daygrid.php?id=' + newID + '&d=' + $.now();
        var passGrdDiv = "div[id=jqgrid" + newID +"]";

        $.get(getGrdURL, function(data)
        { $(passGrdDiv).html(data); }); 

        //$(passGrdDiv).load('90daygrid.php?id=' + newID);

};

//date picker function for adding wells info            
$("button[id^=addday]").click(function() 
{
    var curTab = $('#tabs .ui-tabs-active');
    var curTabName = curTab.text();
    var pos = curTabName.search('-');
    var newID = curTabName.slice(0,pos); //id of the current well
    //var dtTag = '#datepicker' + newID;

    $.get('get90maxday.php?id=' + newID,
        function(data) 
        { 
            var passMax = data;
            var getFrmURL = '90dayadddayform.php?id=' + newID + '&maxday=' + passMax + '&d=' + $.now();
            var passFrmDiv = "div[id^=adddaydata" + newID + "]";

            $.get(getFrmURL, function(data)
            { $(passFrmDiv).html(data); }); 

            //$().text(newID + " " + passAPI);
            //$("#gridarea").load('scadagrid.php?api=' + passAPI + '&start=' + passStart + '&end=' + passEnd);
        }
    );
});
```

And here is the code from the dynamic document that is being loaded;

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];
?>  

<link href="/Includes/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Includes/jqgrid/css/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="/Includes/jqgrid/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Includes/jqgrid/css/jquery-ui-1.11.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Includes/validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Includes/validation/dist/additional-methods.min.js"></script>

<tr>
    <td><label for="dt<?php echo $id; ?>">Date</label></td>
    <td><input id="dt<?php echo $id; ?>" name="dt<?php echo $id;?>" type="text"></td>
</tr>

var passID = $("input[id^=id]").val();
var dtPkr = "input[id=dt" + passID +"]";

$(dtPkr).datepicker();
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated

Comment: your javascript at the bottom of your php file is not inside a script tag. All scripts need to be inside `<script></script>`

Comment: It has the open & closing tags in my code. I did not include all my code, just the relevant parts.

I added one 'non-relevant' function since it is called from the tabs activation sequence where the rest happens.

Comment: edited to add the content for the button click which calls this dynamic document. I did not realize I did not have it in originally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to want to tap into the `activate` event if you've got this hosted in a tab (don't see it in the code, but it's in the question?).  See [jQuery UI Tabs Widget](https://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/) documentation.

You're going to want to add, in `activate` or in your `loadGrid()` function, something to initialize the datepickers:

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker();
```

You would, of course, have to have the datepickers be of class datepicker for that to work.  See [jQuery UI Datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) documentation.

Comment: I have the following under the tabs "activate:function(event, ui)" with more code under it. However this is not being loaded upon activation.

A button is clicked, when the button is clicked it identifies the current tab and loads this content into the current tab. This comment line indentifies where the content is being loaded 'from' in the source document; "//date picker function for adding wells info "

Comment: Let me give a little more background info. I am loading a form, and I am loading a form with complete different names for each tab so there cannot be any possible conflict.

When the date is entered it makes a call to another document uses the date and another passed paramanter, loads information into the rest of the form, and removes the readonly from the other fields. then the user can review the data and populate a couple other required fields. all of this is working. the datepicker can be called from any tab, one time (total), once it is used, one time, it will not work from any tab.

Comment: Updated my answer, above.  I think you're just missing datepicker initialization, is all, in the activate code.

Comment: I was initializing it like this based on the id (see original code for variable definitions, dtPkr is variable) ;  $(dtPkr).datepicker(); I added the following class to my input statement;  class="dt<?php echo $id; ?>" . Now my initialization for datepicker is $('.dt<?php echo $id; ?>').datepicker(); Same exact problem :(   (yes this is a mix of server / client side but it outputs the correct code to the client where it will run from there). The client gets this; class="dt23" in input and initialization of $('.dt23').datepicker();

Comment: OK - I did a 're-write' on this and I was able to get it to work with the class. Originally this was using a button the user would click to pull date in from a 2nd page, including the datepicker. Now instead of a button I put the date on the original page, and I use a class (the same name) for all the datepicker boxes; now they all fire. It appears datepicker fires once, under one name.  it took a revamp but your suggestions lead to the answer.

Comment: kewl.  Glad to have helped!